# ¿Como conectar usuario mysql a un servidor AWS?

Tags: mysql, aws

Estoy usando AWS y acabo de instalar mysql en un ambiente EC2 con ubuntu 14, he creado mi usuario root con el cual me puedo conectar mediante SSH normalmente, pero he creado otro usuario con privilegios grant all para que otra persona pueda subir cambios a una BD y he intentado conectarme mediante un modo standard con el dns publico de mi EC2 pero me rechaza. Que estoy haciendo mal?, me falta configurar algo?... he abierto el puerto 3306 respectivo en mi grupo de seguridad asignado a mi EC2. Espero me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiene toda la pinta de que no has cambiado la dirección de escucha por defecto de tu MySQL, mira ver tu my.cnf a ver si tiene el siguiente valor:

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Si lo tiene coméntalo y reinicia.

Otra Solución, SSH Tunneling:
Algo que puedes hacer para conectar remotamente a un servidor MySQL sin necesidad de abrir ningún puerto, es usar un tunel SSH.

Algo así en Linux:

```
ssh -fNg -L 9999:127.0.0.1:3306 user@yourhost.com
```

Esto habilitará en tu máquina local el puerto 9999 como un "tunnel" al puerto remoteo 3306 local de tu servidor.

Para Windows, quizás usando Putty puedas conseguirlo tb:

Échale un ojo a esto:
http://www.ytechie.com/2008/05/set-up-a-windows-ssh-tunnel-in-10-minutes-or-less/

La mayoría de los clientes gráficos para MySQL permiten conexiones a través de tunneling, como por ejemplo MySQL WorkBench.

https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: Si, gracias por tu ayuda, lo he solucionado, poniendo mi bind-address en 0.0.0.0 y he abierto el puerto 3306 en Ubuntu con la ip de la persona que se conectara y ya funciono. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que tener estas consideraciones:

- Agrega una regla de input en tu security group de tu instancia EC2 al puerto 3306
- Asegúrate que en el archivo my.conf de mysql tenga el parámetro bind-address en 0.0.0.0 (escuche todas la direcciones ip)
- Si hiciste el punto anterior reinicia el servicio de mysql (# service mysqld restart)
- Crear un usuario mysql "create user [nombre]@'%' ... el % es importante ya que indica que el usuario puede acceder desde cualquier dirección IP

Con todo lo anterior no deberías tener problemas, en el punto 2 puedes hacer un

```
$ telnet [dirección ip] 3306
```

para comprobar si el puerto esta escuchando remotamente

Comment: he hecho todo lo que me dices, pero no logro realizar una conexion de un usuario sin autenticacion SSL. He agregado la regla en mi grupo de seguridad apuntando al puerto 3306, pero cuando intento hacer el telnet no se conecta. Tu has logrado hacer esto?

Comment: Listo, logre solucionarlo, me sirvió. Gracias